# Do gas fireplaces need chimney cleaning?

Tags: cleaning, fireplace, maintenance, chimney

Is it necessary to have the chimney cleaned by chimney sweeping service if I use a gas imitation fireplace log (no wood) exclusively?

If so, what is the reason?  What is the root cause for chimneys needing cleaning in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creosote from wood fires is the main reason, so no, cleaning from that standpoint isn't needed.

Comment: And soot from unburned evaporated carbon condensing out of the exhaust gasses. Natural gas is burnt with balanced or excess oxygen so the burn is complete and you should only produce carbon dioxide and water.

Comment: @FiascoLabs, Burning pure Methane with sufficient oxygen is CH4 + 2 O2 → 2 H2O + CO2 a.k.a. carbon dioxide and water like you mention. Natural Gas is not 100% methane. It will still produce carbon monoxide and carbon soot but still no way near the same soot as wood.

Comment: As @HerrBag has stated they don't need cleaning in the conventional sense, they should be inspected periodically. Even if it nothing more than you looking up the flue with a flashlight and mirror.

Comment: @mikes what would one be looking for when inspecting it?

Comment: @glenviewjeff birds nest, dead critter  (unless you have a bullet-proof chimney cap)

Comment: Rust from water condensing in the upper part of the stack, especially if there's any sulfur content in your natural gas. If the liner's stainless, this isn't a problem.

Comment: Sulfuric acid will eventually corrode stainless steel.